# Get substring from xml string objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsscanner

I know this question has been asked many times. I've response string that contains xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>116363111</response>
```

For each request i receive new short xml string, and i need to get value in "response" node. How i can do this, without creating xml parser? I don't want to create xml parser for this short xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use NSScanner and scan from `<response>` up to `</response>`.

```
NSString *xmlString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<response>116363111</response>";

NSString *startTag = @"<response>";
NSString *endTag = @"</response>";
NSString *responseString;

NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:xmlString];
[scanner scanUpToString:startTag intoString:nil];
scanner.scanLocation += [startTag length];
[scanner scanUpToString:endTag intoString:&responseString];
[scanner release];

NSLog(@"Response string is %@", responseString);
```